# Is it possible to load the images sequentially from top to bottom in webpage?

Tags: jquery, css, image, html

I want to load images one by one Sequentially from top to bottom e.g. see the attached image.

[image]

- First load: Image 01
- When completely loaded image 01 then load image 02,
- When completely loaded image 02 then load image 03 and so on...

```css
.my-container {
  width: 1060px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
img {
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="portfolio">
    <img alt="image 01" width="960" height="640" src="http://i.imgur.com/wIfbFMu.jpg">
    <img alt="image 02" width="960" height="640" src="http://i.imgur.com/thiOajQ.jpg">
    <img alt="image 03" width="960" height="720" src="http://i.imgur.com/YgIxbVF.jpg">
    <img alt="image 04" width="960" height="640" src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6R20O.jpg">
    <img alt="image 05" width="960" height="625" src="http://i.imgur.com/XENpTvq.jpg">
    <img alt="image 06" width="960" height="638" src="http://i.imgur.com/qBMOAgZ.jpg">
  </div>
</div><!-- .my-container -->
```

I preferred jQuery solution.

Comment: Good diagram, but where is your code?

Comment: See [jQuery.imageloader()](http://beatak.github.io/jquery-imageloader/)

Comment: @nashcheez thanks, Code is added.

Comment: Do you really mean load them sequentially, or do you mean show them sequentially.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes I really mean to load them Sequentially as same as I explained in diagram.

Comment: Okay, my answer sets that up. The images will load in order.

Comment: To be clear, they'll load in the order in which they appear in the document. So, if for whatever reason your "Image 06" appears before "Image 05" in the document, but is lower because of CSS or something, it will load first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set up a function that loads the image at the current index, and increments the index when the image has loaded.

Using the `data-src` attribute makes it so that the image does not load until the URL is put into the `src` attribute.

I've added a console log to show that the images are loading sequentially.

```js
$(function () {
   var $images = $('.portfolio img');
   var lastLoadIndex = 0;
   var loadNextImage = function () {
      if ($images.length === lastLoadIndex) {
          return;
      }
console.log('loading image at index ' + lastLoadIndex);
      $images.eq(lastLoadIndex).attr('src', $images.eq(lastLoadIndex).attr('data-src'));
      lastLoadIndex += 1;
   };
   $images.on('load', loadNextImage);
   loadNextImage();
});
```

```css
.my-container {
  width: 1060px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}
img {
  margin: 0 auto 35px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="portfolio">
    <img alt="image 01" width="960" height="640" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/wIfbFMu.jpg">
    <img alt="image 02" width="960" height="640" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/thiOajQ.jpg">
    <img alt="image 03" width="960" height="720" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/YgIxbVF.jpg">
    <img alt="image 04" width="960" height="640" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/Xt6R20O.jpg">
    <img alt="image 05" width="960" height="625" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/XENpTvq.jpg">
    <img alt="image 06" width="960" height="638" data-src="http://i.imgur.com/qBMOAgZ.jpg">
  </div>
</div><!-- .my-container -->
```

Comment: It looks great, I'm testing it, then I will accept the answer. thank you for the great code.

Comment: I've tested. Thank you so much for help, you made the exactly same thing as what I expected, you are a genius.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JS solution.

```js
    function init() {
      var imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll(".img-sequence");
      var lastLoadIndex = 0;
      function loadNextImage() {
        if (imgDefer.length === lastLoadIndex) {
          return;
        }
        imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].addEventListener("load", loadNextImage);
        imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].setAttribute(
          "src",
          imgDefer[lastLoadIndex].getAttribute("data-src")
        );
        lastLoadIndex += 1;
      };
      loadNextImage();
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

```html
<div>
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=0" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=1" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=2" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=3" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=4" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=5" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=6" />
 <img class="img-sequence" data-src="https://picsum.photos/320/320?image=7" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just with some jquery rows to show it sequentially from top to bottom. It isn't working on stack overflow snippet but you can try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/wtgjhrv6/ .

```js
$('img').each(function(fadeInImg) {
     $(this).delay(fadeInImg * 500).fadeIn(1000);
   });
```

```css
img {
  display:none;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
</div>
```

2nd request load content when it's on viewport, you can use the wow.js library to do it faster. You can try it here https://jsfiddle.net/o9aLv51g/

```js
new WOW().init();
```

```css
img {
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<div>
    
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
   <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
    <img class="wow fadeIn" src="http://www.nathab.com/uploaded-files/carousels/TRIPS/Photo-Wolves/2a-Wolves-photo-holdsworth.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your work but it's not what I'm expecting, see your code loading all images together not sequentially. https://jsfiddle.net/o9aLv51g/1/

Comment: please read comment, try it on jsfiddle. The first load it sequentially, the second load images that just are on viewport. I've put js fiddle link to test it.

Comment: I've tried your jsfiddle and it load images sequentially when they are on viewport. If you want to add a little delay to make it more visible add **<img src="link.jpg" class="wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="1s">**

Comment: I've improved question and Added better diagram which explain exactly what I'm expecting. I don't want any delay or fake fade-in effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload plugin.

```
 <img class="lazy" data-original="img/example.jpg" width="640" height="480">

$(function() {
   $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});
```

Comment: It's good plugin but doesn't do what I'm expecting, it loads image when it's visible inside view-port, I want to load images sequentially from top to bottom one by one.

Comment: Then @vlk answer seems ok